# How to filter a date-field with a swift vapor-fluent query

Tags: sql, swift, postgresql, fluent, vapor

To avoid multiple inserts of the same person in a database, I wrote the following function:

```
func anzahlDoubletten(_ req: Request, nname: String, vname: String, gebTag: Date) 
   async throws -> Int {                                                                                 
    try await                                                                                            
        Teilnehmer.query(on: req.db)                                                                     
        .filter(\.$nname == nname)                                                                       
        .filter(\.$vname == vname)                                                                       
        .filter(\.$gebTag == gebTag)                                                                     
        .count()                                                                                         
}
```

The function always returns 0, even if there are multiple records with the same surname, prename and birthday in the database.

Here is the resulting sql-query:

```
[ DEBUG ] SELECT COUNT("teilnehmer"."id") AS "aggregate" FROM "teilnehmer" WHERE "teilnehmer"."nname" = $1 AND "teilnehmer"."vname" = $2 AND "teilnehmer"."geburtstag" = $3 ["neumann", "alfred e.", 1999-09-09 00:00:00 +0000] [database-id: psql, request-id: 1AC70C41-EADE-43C2-A12A-99C19462EDE3] (FluentPostgresDriver/FluentPostgresDatabase.swift:29)
[ INFO ] anzahlDoubletten=0 [request-id: 1AC70C41-EADE-43C2-A12A-99C19462EDE3] (App/Controllers/TeilnehmerController.swift:49)
```

if I query directly I obtain:

```
lwm=# select nname, vname, geburtstag from teilnehmer;
  nname  |   vname   | geburtstag 
---------+-----------+------------
 neumann | alfred e. | 1999-09-09
 neumann | alfred e. | 1999-09-09
 neumann | alfred e. | 1999-09-09
 neumann | alfred e. | 1999-09-09
```

so count() should return 4 not 0:

```
lwm=# select count(*) from teilnehmer where nname = 'neumann' and vname = 'alfred e.' and geburtstag = '1999-09-09';
 count 
-------
     4
```

My DateFormatter is defined like so:

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()                                                                                                                                                                 
        dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withDashSeparatorInDate]
```

And finally the attribute "birthday" in my model:

```
...
@Field(key: "geburtstag")
var gebTag: Date
...
```

I inserted the 4 alfreds in my database using the model and fluent, passing the birthday "1999-09-09" as a String and fluent inserted all records correctly.

But `.filter(\.$gebTag == gebTag)` seems to return constantly 'false'.

Is it at all possible to use .filter() with data types other than String?

And if so, what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for your help

Michael

Comment: What are the values that you’re comparing?

Comment: Date-objects, built from Strings using the mentioned dateFormatter: `let gebTag = dateFormatter.date(from: "19999-09-09!)!` . The very same objects I use to insert records into the database. Insertion works perfectly, column-type in the db is "date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've hit is that you're storing only dates whereas you're filtering on dates with times. Unfortunately there's no native way to store just a date. However there are a few options.

The easiest way is to change the date field to a `String` and then use your date formatter (make sure you remove the time part) to convert the query option to a String.

Comment: Hi Tim, yes, I should have read the pg-doc on date/time -types as it reads: 'date  4 bytes  date (no time of day)' . I changed db-date-type to 'timestamp with time-zone' . Now the filter works correctly.

Comment: I don’t want to sound picky but you’ve implanted my answer and accepted the other one!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing slightly here, but I suspect that your table was not created by a `Migration`? If it had been, your `geburtstag` field would include a time component as this is the default and you would have spotted the problem quickly.

In any event, the `filter` is actually filtering on the time component of `gebTag` as well as the date. This is why it is returning zero.

I suggest converting the `geburtstag` to a type that includes the time and ensuring that the time component is set to 0:00:00 when you store it. You can reset the time component to 'midnight' using something like this:

```swift
extension Date {
    var midnight: Date { return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)! }
}
```

Then change your filter to:

```swift
    .filter(\.$gebTag == gebTag.midnight)
```

Alternatively, just use the static method in Calendar:

```swift
    .filter(\.$gebTag == Calendar.startOfDay(for:gebTag))
```

I think this is the most straightforward way of doing it.

Comment: Hi Nick, yes, you are guessing right: I create the database running a sql-script. I changed the type of 'birthday' in the pg-db to 'timestamp with time zone' an now the filter returns true. Passing the String '1999-09-09' to my dateFormatter inserts '1999-09-09 00:00:00 +0000' into the table. So that even works with my original filter-code. Nevertheless I will try your suggested extension.

Comment: Setting the time to midnight, fluent now tries to filter alfred's birthday as `1999-09-08 22:00:00 +0000`. Somehow it takes into account my local time-zone (CEST = UTC +2).